# Is it safe to wipe out pgsql_tmp while the database is not running?

Tags: postgresql, recovery, postgresql-13

I've had a couple of instances recently of being forced to shut down my PostgreSQL 13.10 database uncleanly, and it taking a few hours to come back up afterwards.

In both cases, strace revealed that what the process was doing was `stat`-ing (maybe `lstat`, I forget) and then deleting (`unlink`) files from `base/pgsql_tmp`. This took hours because there were tens of millions of files in there (which itself is unusual, but probably just a symptom of the issues that forced the unclean shutdown).

My question is: is it just blindly deleting all the temporary files, or does it use some of them in the recovery process? If it's just blindly deleting them, I imagine I might be able to improve recovery time by deleting them more quickly (e.g. moving the whole directory aside, giving the server a fresh one, and then deleting it at my leisure).

Of course, messing with the internals of the data directory is always fraught, but I also have regular disk snapshots, so even in the worst case it's only a day or so of data loss. With that in mind, reducing the downtime from a few hours to a few minutes seems worth a little risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely safe to delete all files in the `pgsql_tmp` of any tablespace (`base` being the default tablespace). The question is whether manually deleting the files will be slower than PostgreSQL doing it or not.

I recommend that you set the `temp_file_limit` parameter to limit how much temporary data a PostgreSQL session can write.